# If environment settings are to be made persistent, where should I store them?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, .bash-profile

I want to make environment settings persistent. Where should I store them? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

You store them in `.bashrc`

As per the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for bash, .bash_profile is executed for login shells, while .bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells.

An explanation of `bash_profile` and `.bashrc` can be found [here](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile).